# Android emulator not booting in VM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

I am using Android Studio with version 3.1.2 in my Virtual Machine. I created on AVD with ARM image in it and try to run it by using the following command

```
emulator -avd Pixel_API_27 -netspeed full -netdelay none -no-snapshot -debug-init -logcat '*:v'
```

It is able to open the emulator, but showing the black screen. And in the terminal log I am seeing the following log with the began of crash

```
 01-01 00:00:15.594 657 657 D libEGL : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-01 00:00:16.670 657 657 D gralloc_ranchu: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected. Loading gralloc.default.so from /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so...
01-01 00:00:16.682 657 657 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc.default.so not found in /vendor. Trying /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so...
01-01 00:00:16.729 657 657 E hwcomposer: ranchu_hw_composer hwc_open could not open framebuffer
01-01 00:00:16.752 657 657 I SurfaceFlinger: Using composer version 1.1
--------- beginning of crash
01-01 00:00:16.758 657 657 F libc : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x44 in tid 657 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:00:17.085 647 674 V vold : /dev/block/vold/disk:254,48: LABEL="SDCARD" UUID="1711-2E16" TYPE="vfat"
01-01 00:00:17.153 662 662 I SELinux : SELinux: Loaded file_contexts contexts from /file_contexts.
01-01 00:00:17.256 662 662 F DEBUG : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:00:17.257 662 662 F DEBUG : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:6.0/MASTER/4729342:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:00:17.258 662 662 F DEBUG : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:00:17.258 662 662 F DEBUG : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:00:17.261 662 662 F DEBUG : pid: 657, tid: 657, name: surfaceflinger >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:00:17.312 662 662 F DEBUG : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x44
01-01 00:00:17.578 662 662 F DEBUG : r0 b6682000 r1 00000000 r2 00000000 r3 00000001
01-01 00:00:17.579 662 662 F DEBUG : r4 00000000 r5 b6682000 r6 beb6b9e8 r7 b6f7e5b0
01-01 00:00:17.579 662 662 F DEBUG : r8 00000000 r9 b65e5b2d sl b65e5c92 fp 00000000
01-01 00:00:17.579 662 662 F DEBUG : ip 00000000 sp beb6b788 lr b6f70281 pc b65e3600 cpsr 80000170
01-01 00:00:18.006 662 662 F DEBUG :
01-01 00:00:18.006 662 662 F DEBUG : backtrace:
01-01 00:00:18.007 662 662 F DEBUG : #00 pc 00001600 /system/lib/hw/hwcomposer.ranchu.so
01-01 00:00:18.007 662 662 F DEBUG : #01 pc 0002327f /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:00:18.008 662 662 F DEBUG : #02 pc 00022d59 /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:00:18.009 662 662 F DEBUG : #03 pc 000188df /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+98)
01-01 00:00:18.009 662 662 F DEBUG : #04 pc 00000e9d /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:00:18.010 662 662 F DEBUG : #05 pc 0001733d /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
01-01 00:00:18.010 662 662 F DEBUG : #06 pc 00000d60 /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:00:28.838 665 665 I mediaserver: ServiceManager: 0xb604e120
01-01 00:00:28.840 665 665 I AudioFlinger: Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
01-01 00:00:28.923 665 665 E : batterystats service unavailable!
01-01 00:00:28.927 665 665 E : batterystats service unavailable!
01-01 00:00:28.957 665 665 I CameraService: CameraService started (pid=665)
01-01 00:00:28.958 665 665 I CameraService: CameraService process starting
01-01 00:00:28.963 665 665 E : batterystats service unavailable!
01-01 00:00:28.982 665 665 E : batterystats service unavailable!
01-01 00:00:29.345 665 665 D EmulatedCamera_QemuClient: Emulated camera list: name=virtualscene channel=0 pix=876758866 dir=back framedims=640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144,1280x720,1280x960
```

It is repeating the same error continuously. 
Please help me to resolve this. I need to run the emulator only because I am using the VM

Thanks In Advance

Comment: have you tested a software-rendered emulator too? does it work? By default, emulator is hardware-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it could be related to "Use Host GPU" option. Check it on tick box emulator setting (deactive or active it) or Select 'Software GLES 2.0' to disable host GPU in Emulated performance and try again. i hope help you

Comment: I didn't found "USE Host GPU" option under emulator -> settings

Comment: @Mallikarjuna in 'Emulated Performance' , Select 'Software GLES 2.0' to disable host GPU